# How to change UIviewController inside NSObject class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a class called Packet which responsible for receiving packets.
inside this class I want to change the view controller
the current view controller is: `JoinViewController`.
the class defined as

```
@interface Packet : NSObject
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work here is code:

```
 case PacketTypeMytype:
    {
        GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
        JoinViewController *join=[[JoinViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"JoinViewController" bundle:nil];

        [[join navigationController]pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of `JoinViewController` to the packet object (as a weak reference) instead of creating a new one.

Comment: should I have to make a property inside the Packet class

Comment: Yes, exactly, create a weak property